# Fill textbox with multiple email address from dropdownlist and seperate by comma in asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one text box and one dropdownlist. The dropdownlist stores all the email address. I would like populate the textbox with multiple email address and each address is separated by comma when the dropdownlist text is changed. I tried something like this:

```
 static string emailList;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void DropDownList1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        emailList = emailList + DropDownList1.Text + ",";
        emails.Text = emailList;

    }
```

but it does not work as expected since the comma also included at the front of the first email address.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The comma here is added at the end not _at the front_

Comment: just replace the last comma with empty string.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to have the comma only between email addresses, so

```
protected void DropDownList1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailList))
        emailList = DropDownList1.Text;
    else
        emailList += "," + DropDownList1.Text;
    emails.Text = emailList;
}
```

I assume that you have omitted the code that reloads the emailList between Postback.

Answer (score 0):

This also can be done this way:

```
       if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailList))
        {
            emailList = DropDownList1.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            var tempEailList = emailList.Split(',').ToList();
            tempEailList.Add(DropDownList1.Text);

            emailList = string.Join(",", tempEailList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more efficient way to do this.

```
List<string> emailAddresses = new List<string>(); ;
foreach(ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
{
     emailAddresses.Add(item.Text);
}
string emailList = string.Join(",", emailAddresses.ToArray());
```